# preg_replace td in table

Tags: php, html, mysql, preg-replace

I have in MYSQL stored HTML table.
I need to modify the values ​​of some td.

For example:

```
<tr>...<td class="(different classes)" name="myNameA">20</td>...</tr>
<tr>...<td class="(different classes)" name="myNameB">10</td>...</tr>
```

I need:

```
<tr>...<td class="(different classes)" name="myNameA">(20 * 0,60)</td>...</tr>
<tr>...<td class="(different classes)" name="myNameB">(10 * 0,60)</td>...</tr>
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Because I can import the data only as html, but I need this modified .

Comment: Better to use a DOM parser library than regexp.

Answer (score 0):

here is what you need :)

```
$re = '/(<tr>(?:.*?)<td (?:.*?) name="myNameA">)(.*?)(<\/td>(?:.*?)<\/tr>)/'; 
$str = '<tr>...<td class="(different classes)" name="myNameA">20</td>...</tr>\n<tr>...<td class="(different classes)" name="myNameB">10</td>...</tr>'; 

preg_replace_callback(
        $re,
        function ($matches) {
            echo htmlspecialchars(strtolower($matches[1]).'('.strtolower($matches[2]).' * 0,60)'.strtolower($matches[3]));
        },
        $str
    );
```

***output***

```
<tr>...<td class="(different classes)" name="mynamea">(20 * 0,60)</td>...</tr>
```

for matching `myNameB` change the `myNameA` to `myNameB` and to display this as html instead of text remove `htmlspecialchars()` function from code

Comment: thank you so much:) Please, How I can use this statement only for `name="mynameA"` and `name="mynameB"` and show like a `html`, not text?

Comment: i've changed my answer ,see my answer

Comment: is it helped you bro?

Comment: Yes, you are awesome :) I have one last question. Please, how to solve this: If `<tr>` contains `<td>300x200</ td>`, releases this `<tr>`. Thx.